# Following a tutorial but can't figure out why I'm getting this message: "Property 'substring' does not exist on type '() => WordArray'.ts(2339)"

Tags: javascript, substring

I'm a beginner following a yt blockchain tutorial on visual code yet i'm getting this message when using substring: `Property 'substring' does not exist on type '() => WordArray'.ts(2339)`

```
class Block {
    constructor(index, timestamp, data, previousHash = ''){
        this.index = index;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.data = data;
        this.previousHash = previousHash;
        this.hash = this.calculateHash;
        this.nonce = 0;
    }

    calculateHash(){
        return SHA256(this.index + this.previousHash + this.timestamp + JSON.stringify(this.data) + this.nonce.toString());

    }

    mineBlock(difficulty){
        while(this.hash().substring(0, difficulty) !== Array(difficulty + 1).join("0")){
            this.nonce++;
            this.hash = this.calculateHash();
        }
    
        console.log("Block mined: " + this.hash);
    }

}
```

Comment: are you using the `CryptoJS` version of `SHA256`?

Answer (score 0):

`this.hash` is a function that returns some kind of list. There is no `substring` method on the function itself, only on the result.

You need to use `this.hash()` to call the function to get its result. Then `this.hash().substring` might work.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately, still has the same message

Comment: Please include the code in the post. Not a screenshot. @Koala

Comment: I'm using mac & substring isn't appearing under the suggestions list as it is on the tutorial.

Comment: Please include the definition of this.hash

Comment: Ive included it now

Comment: What does SHA256 return? Include that too.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are trying to use `substring` method on a non `String` class.
I'm going to assume you're using the `CryptoJS` implementation of `SHA256` given the capitalization. If not I'll delete the answer, but you need to convert the hash to a `String` class in order to use the `substring` method. The `SHA256` does not return a string and you need to convert it to one in order to apply string methods to it.
Changing the `calculateHash` method to this should make the code work:

```js
calculateHash(){
  return SHA256(this.index + this.previousHash + this.timestamp + JSON.stringify(this.data) + this.nonce.toString()).toString();
  }
```

More info can be found in the [docs](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/)